# Map nested class models

Tags: c#, .net

**From a Web API Call, I received the Response and stored it in this model**

```
public class DetailedTogglResponse
{
    public List<TogglDetailedReport> data { get; set; }
    public string total_grand { get; set; }
    public string total_billable { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code of the said Model :

```
public class TogglDetailedReport
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public int? tid { get; set; }
    public int uid { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public int dur { get; set; }
    public String client { get; set; }
    public Decimal billable { get; set; }
    public bool is_billable { get; set; }
    public String cur { get; set; }
    public List<String> tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags
{
    public String TagName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to "Auto Map" with `TogglDetailedReport`, `DetailedReport` (part of the code only, doesn't show `List<Tags> tags { get; set; }`)

How to "Auto Map" TogglDetailedReport to DetailedReport ?

```
public class DetailedReport
{
    public int TimeEntryId { get; set; } // TimeEntryId (Primary key)
    public int ProjectId { get; set; } // ProjectId
    public int? TaskId { get; set; } // TaskId
    public int UserId { get; set; } // UserId
    public string Description { get; set; } // Description (length: 250)
    public string ClientName { get; set; } // ClientName (length: 50)
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; } // StartTime
    public System.DateTime EndTime { get; set; } // EndTime
    public int Duration { get; set; } // Duration
    public decimal Billable { get; set; } // Billable
    public bool IsBillable { get; set; } // IsBillable
    public string Currency { get; set; } // Currency (length: 10)
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } // CreatedDate
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? And also, which library are you using?

Comment: By auto map, what do you mean ? Associating the corresponding value in the object ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you've received the response and have it in a model already there is nothing to map further. Do you have the model object already or you have a JSON string?